# Cannot Copy Class In Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Copy class and paste it in package cannot be used I encountered this morning by hotkey(Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V) or mouse operation.
Only could by show in explorer, copy class and then paste it to package.
After restore default setting and reinstall idea, issue didn't fixed.

Comment: System is WIN10, IDEA VERSOIN is 2020.2.3

Comment: Is there anything relevant in idea.log (Help | Show log...)?